# How to change the default app running window to secondary window in android from android studio

Tags: android

I'm trying to run my application in secondary display but by default it's going to default display.

Please note that the board I'm using supports multiple physical display and I'm developing apps for secondary display.

Comment: what does you exactly want to do? can you explain .

Comment: Please explain, in programming terms, what "run my application in secondary window" means and what "going to default window" means. For example, you might provide a [mcve] illustrating what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm having a display which is splitted into two window. Android default runs to the default window (Id: 0) and I have to develop an application which will run on second window(Id: 1). Through command line i can run this way: am start -n com.app/.ui.activities.Dashboard --display 1 but i want to make it on android studio run button.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Run > Edit Configurations > Launch Options > Launch Flags add this:

```
--display 1
```